# My Motherboard has 3 display outputs. Can I use 3 Screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard, display, computer-building

I am just building my first computer (going to instal linux, probably Ubuntu).  I have been a Mac boy for the last four years so I am feeling somewhat confused.

I am thinking about getting this [ASUS P8H67-M LE B3 Intel H67 Motherboard](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=7343096&CatId=6977) for $99 CAD.

According to the specs it has these display ports:

- VGA Ports:   1
- DVI Ports:   1
- HDMI Ports:  1

Here are my questions:

1. Since the computer has 3 ports for displays does that mean that I can plug in 3 displays?  Will they all work at the same time?  Will they mirror each other?
2. If I can only use one display at the same time AND I buy a video card with one additional vga output.  Will This allow me to use two screens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The H67 supports 2 outputs: HDMI, and DVI-I. The VGA is a peel-out from the DVI-I and does not function independently.
2. Yes, depending on the OS.

Comment: How do you know this?  Do you know this from reading the spec or do you *just know*.  I want to avoid asking the same question again.

Comment: It's listed in the product brief as "Dual Independent Display", and VGA is not listed anywhere meaning that it must be a peel-out. http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/chipsets/ec-h67/h67-overview.htm

Answer (score 2):

1. According to the chipset specs, you can use up to two monitors with that motherboard using only the integrated ports. If you use all 3, I assume that one of them won't work, due to chipset limitations. If you use 2 displays, they, according to the specs, will not mirror unless they are set to, and will all work at the same time.
2. As for adding a video card with a vga output, on some boards/chipsets this will work and on some it will not. Some choose to disable the onboard video when a pcie/pci card is attached. YMMV. Considering that it's a new board, I'd say it'll most likely work.

Comment: Where in the specs do you see that?

Comment: If you're talking about the chipset specs, I found them at http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/chipsets/ec-h67/h67-overview.htm . It's under the "Support for HDMI, etc" section.